# Hbase 1.1.2 Common Connection

Tags: java, connection, hbase

I have created a hbase scan method, but I am creating and closing the Connection inside the method itself. Could anyone suggest how to create a common connection, so that I can use the connection for a put, etc
 I was not sure when to close the connection.

public class HBaseConnection {

```
private static  Connection connection;

public void scanHBase(String tableName, byte[] startRow, byte[] stopRow) throws IOException {
    connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(hBaseConn);
    Table tableRef = connection.getTable(tableName);
    Scan scan = new Scan(startRow, stopRow);
    ResultScanner scanner = tableRef.getScanner(scan);
    System.out.println("Starting scan");
    for (Result res : scanner) {
       //do something
    }
    scanner.close();
    tableRef.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

}

The Connection object that I created inside the scanHBase() I need to create it outside as well as close it outside. Is there a possibility for this. I am new to Java and new to Hbase as

Comment: You can either create your connection in a static block, or create it somewhere else and set it to the HbaseConnection.connection with a setter or by making this object public

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I will not be able to use a static block as I am getting the config from the constructor. I tried using the @PostConstruct, but it does not persist. I.e the connection object is created but when calling in the method I am getting a null pointer. But i tried to create the connection in the constructor itself it works fine. But, I don't think it is a best practice to create a connection in the constructor. If you could elaborate or shed some other ideas that would be great. Also colsing the connection is proving to be a hassle.

Comment: Two more solution came to my mind. One you can create a connection somewhere else (like in a connection factory) and pass it as an argument to each constructor (or getting from the factory inside the constructor). The other (not really good ) solution is to define a static connection and in the constructor check if it is null, create the object, if not just use it

Comment: That worked thank you very much for your suggessions. Can you plz write the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can define the shared connection as static and instantiate it in a static block.
2. You can create a connection somewhere else (like in a connection factory) and pass it as an argument to each constructor (or getting from the factory inside the constructor).
3. The other (not really good) solution is to define a static connection and in the constructor check if it is null, create the object, if not just use it